# React js when changing path from <Link> it doesn't because it doesn't finish loading the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, react-router-dom

What I want to do is when you hit an element that has a  set to render another component.
But what is happening to me is when I give it the other component does not render because the previous one has not finished loading the images that it has.
So is there not a way that even if I am loading the images I change my component and not expect it to load everything in order to go to the other component?

Here I leave my code where I have the routes and how I call another component through the Link.

````
  return (
      <BrowserRouter>                
        <Route exact path="/viewService/:id" component={VerServicio} />
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route exact path="/signup" component={Register} />
        <Route exact path="/myprofile" component={MyProfile} />
        <Route exact path="/newservice" component={NewService} />
        <Route exact path="/editservice/:id" component={NewService} />
        <Route exact path="/pruebas" component={Pruebas} />
        <Route component={Home} />
      </BrowserRouter>      
      // <NewService></NewService>
  );
}```
````

```
<Link to={{ pathname: "/viewService/" + currentData.id, state: {currentData}}}>
    <input type="hidden" id="serviceID" name="serviceID" value={currentData.id} />
    <input type="hidden" id="userID" name="userID" value={currentData.user_id} />
    <img className="card-img-top" alt={currentData.alt} src={(this.props.url+currentData.serviceImage[0].attachment)}></img>
    <div className="card-body card-mod-text">
        <h6 className="card-text mt-1 font-weight-bold">{currentData.title}</h6>
        <p className="card-text font-weight-bold">{currentData.price}€/h · <span className="texto-dis">25 km de mi</span></p>
    </div>
</Link>
```

Comment: What exactly are you seeing happen when you click the link?
And what leads you to believe that image loading is the cause of your problem?

Comment: when I click it I see that the path /"example" changes but the component doesn't render.
And what makes me believe this is because when I click on the browser to stop loading this page and then click on it at that moment if it renders the following component @Ace

Comment: That's weird. So does  clicking the link also work if you wait until the images load?